# List.Generate is looping infinitely with empty lists

Tags: rest, powerbi, pagination, powerquery, reporting

I am pretty fresh to the power query language and have ran into an issue when trying to Paginate through a RestAPI.

Currently I am using the a pretty stock list.generate loop:

```
= List.Generate(()=>
        [x = try GetData(1) otherwise null, Page=1],
    each [x]<>null, 
    each [x = try GetData([Page]+1) otherwise null, Page=[Page]+1],
    each[x])
```

This is returning me lists of records as expected, but once the records dry up it continues to create empty lists with no records.
[Vision of list with Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RekGz.png)
[Vision of list without Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0XqL.png)

Here is my Current thoughts

```
= List.Generate(()=>
        [x = try GetData(1) otherwise null, Page=1],
    each not List.IsEmpty[x], 
    each [x = try GetData([Page]+1) otherwise null, Page=[Page]+1],
    each[x])
```

I believe that a List.IsEmpty like above should work in this situation but it is returning a
*An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Function.
Details:
Value=[Function]
Key=x*
IT feels like the issues lies with the nested Records which to me read as List[List[Record]] if that makes any sense.
Any help at all would be great
Thanks

Comment: Not a specific answer but look at https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: I think you are missing `(...)` - should be `each not List.IsEmpty([x])`